# migrate embedded tomcat 5 to tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat

Attempting to migrate embedded Tomcat 5 to embedded Tomcat 7. Getting a NPE during the start.

I extend the Embedded class and do all the suggested initialization in the proper sequence.

The NPE occurs here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.populateSessionTrackingModes(ApplicationContext.java:1187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.<init>(ApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getServletContext(StandardContext.java:2344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory(StandardContext.java:6283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

Here is the tomcat 7 source for the method throwing the exception:

```
private void populateSessionTrackingModes() {
    // URL re-writing is always enabled by default
    defaultSessionTrackingModes = EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.URL);
    supportedSessionTrackingModes = EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.URL);

    if (context.getCookies()) {
        defaultSessionTrackingModes.add(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE);
        supportedSessionTrackingModes.add(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE);
    }

    // SSL not enabled by default as it can only used on its own
    // Context > Host > Engine > Service
    Service s = ((Engine) context.getParent().getParent()).getService();
    Connector[] connectors = s.findConnectors();
    // Need at least one SSL enabled connector to use the SSL session ID.
    for (Connector connector : connectors) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(connector.getAttribute("SSLEnabled"))) {
            supportedSessionTrackingModes.add(SessionTrackingMode.SSL);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem happens here:

```
Service s = ((Engine) context.getParent().getParent()).getService();
```

The Service variable s is null. It appears that a service object needs to be set on the Engine class.

Is this something new in Tomcat 7?
Not sure what needs to be configured to avoid this null value for Service.

Comment: Which one is line 1187? Is it `Service s = ((Engine) context.getParent().getParent()).getService();` or `Connector[] connectors = s.findConnectors();`?

Comment: s.findConnectors() is line 1187. The variable is set to null in line 1186 and then used in 1187 which causes the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

The Service is the object that links an Engine with one or more Connectors. Create a default instance of `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService` and use that. Add the connectors to it with `addConnector()` and add the Engine to it with `addContainer()`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

The javadoc for the Embedded class lists the steps and sequence of actions to do. It makes no mention of creating and adding a Service class. Are you saying that documentation is incorrect?

Plus, Embedded, the class I am extending, already extends StandardService. Do I still need to create another one?

Comment: I don't use the Embedded class - I use the newer Tomcat class. It looks like the Embedded class needs a few tweaks (or the docs needs to be updated). You should be able to call setService() on your Engine instance passing the Embedded instance.