# ApplicationContext.populateSessionTrackingModes in Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7

We are currently migrating from Tomcat **Apache 5.5.9 to  Tomcat 7.0.10** but getting a `null pointer exception` when the application is executed.

The exception is same as mentioned in the question

[migrate embedded tomcat 5 to tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077352/migrate-embedded-tomcat-5-to-tomcat-7)

If anybody has another suggestions please let me know. I tried in almost all the version of tomcat 7.0.x but still the same issue.

I am attaching the call stack of the dump.

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.populateSessionTrackingModes(ApplicationContext.java:1188)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.<init>(ApplicationContext.java:127)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getServletContext(StandardContext.java:2211)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory(StandardContext.java:5989)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4960)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.startInternal(Embedded.java:823)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
```

---

Hi Thomas Thanks a lot for your reply .The complete call stack is as follows Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.populateSessionTrackingModes(ApplicationContext.java:1188)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.(ApplicationContext.java:127)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getServletContext(StandardContext.java:2211)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory(StandardContext.java:5989)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4960)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.startInternal(Embedded.java:823)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
               at com.start.las.ls.lmsembed.tomcat.TomcatEmbed.setStatus(TomcatEmbed.java:93)

Comment: I've removed the request for a personal email. If you want to ask for clarification, please use a comment on his answer. And FWIW, @ tagging a user in a question doesn't send them any kind of notifications.

Comment: The full stack trace would be helpful as well as some background on what config has been performed since you'll never see a stack trace like that on a clean install.

Comment: Hi Thomas Thanks a lot for your reply I have put the complete call stack it starts from com.start.las.ls.lmsembed.tomcat.TomcatEmbed.setStatus(TomcatEmbed.java:93)

Comment: We are not running the application from tomcat server we are using certain jar files from the tomcat and then running the application.We are migrating from tomcat 5.0.x jar files to 7.0.x jar files .